# How do I overload an operator for an enumeration in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, operators, operator-overloading

I have an enumerated type that I would like to define the `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` operators for. I know that these operators are implictly created on the basis of the enumerated type (as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#enumeration-comparison-operators)) but I would like to explictly define these operators (for clarity, for control, to know how to do it, etc...)

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
public enum SizeType
{
    Small = 0,
    Medium = 1,
    Large = 2,
    ExtraLarge = 3
}

public SizeType operator >(SizeType x, SizeType y)
{

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work ("unexpected token") ... is this possible?  It seems like it should be since there are implictly defined operators.  Any suggestions?

Comment: For those who do not read questions attentively and at least read comments, **`>, <, >=, and <= operators are implicitly created on the basis of the enumerated type`** - so maybe you don't need any custom stuff. I wrote the whole wrapping struct and then realized things work without it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't do that. You can only provide overloaded operators for classes and structs you define -- and at least one of the parameters should be of type of the class or struct itself. That is, you *can* declare an overloaded addition operator that adds a `MyClass` to `MyEnum` but you can never do that with two `MyEnum` values.

Comment: That is disapointing, how do they do that implictly then?  It seemed like there wouldn't be a way, but I figured if you could do it implicitly then there should be a way to do it explictly.  I guess not.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: They don't. There's no *implicit* way either. You simply can't overload operators for enums.

Comment: According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664726(VS.71).aspx ... "Every enumeration type implicitly provides the following predefined comparison operators:" ... I was just hoping there was a way to explicitly provide a comparison operator similarly.  So not an overload operator exactly, but something simlar.

Comment: Aha. I thought you mean you can implement an implicit operator for enum. The key word in the statement you referred to is *predefined*. The thing is, you can't define any custom operator implementations for enums.

Comment: Well this was an annoying bug to find.

Answer (score 26):

As other mentioned before, one cannot override operators on Enums, but you can do it on struct. See an example below. Let me know if it helped:

```
public struct SizeType
{
    private int InternalValue { get; set; }

    public static readonly int Small = 0;
    public static readonly int Medium = 1;
    public static readonly int Large = 2;
    public static readonly int ExtraLarge = 3;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        SizeType otherObj = (SizeType)obj;
        return otherObj.InternalValue.Equals(this.InternalValue);
    }

    public static bool operator >(SizeType left, SizeType right)
    {
        return (left.InternalValue > right.InternalValue);
    }

    public static bool operator <(SizeType left, SizeType right)
    {
        return (left.InternalValue < right.InternalValue);
    }

    public static implicit operator SizeType(int otherType)
    {
        return new SizeType
        {
            InternalValue = otherType
        };
    }
}

public class test11
{
    void myTest()
    {
        SizeType smallSize = SizeType.Small;
        SizeType largeType = SizeType.Large;
        if (smallSize > largeType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("small is greater than large");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An enum can be used in a switch statement whereas a struct can not.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk this semi-changed in C# 7.0 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Answer (score 22):

According to ECMA-335 Common Language Infrastructure:

> The CTS supports an enum (also known as an enumeration type), an
>   alternate name for an existing type. For the purposes of matching
>   signatures, an enum shall not be the same as the underlying type.
>   Instances of an enum, however, shall be assignable-to the underlying
>   type, and vice versa. That is, no cast (see §8.3.3) or coercion (see
>   §8.3.2) is required to convert from the enum to the underlying type,
>   nor are they required from the underlying type to the enum. An enum is
>   considerably more restricted than a true type, as follows: It shall
>   have exactly one instance field, and the type of that field defines
>   the underlying type of the enumeration.
>
> - It shall not have any methods of its own.
> - It shall derive from System.Enum (see Partition IV Library – Kernel Package).
> - It shall not implement any interfaces of its own.
> - It shall not have any properties or events of its own.
> - It shall not have any static fields unless they are literal. (see §8.6.1.2)

Let's assume that we've got following IL code:

```
.class public auto ansi sealed Test.Months extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
  .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
  .field public static literal valuetype Test.Months January = int32(0x00000001)
  .field public static literal valuetype Test.Months February = int32(0x00000002)
  .field public static literal valuetype Test.Months March = int32(0x00000003)
  // ...

  .method public hidebysig specialname static valuetype Test.Months 
  op_Increment(valuetype Test.Months m) cil managed
  {
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 10
    IL_0003: add
    IL_0004: ret
  }
} // end of class Test.Months
```

MSIL compiler (ilasm.exe) will generate following error:

> ```
> error -- Method in enum
> ***** FAILURE *****
> ```

So we can't overload enum operator even editing IL code ;)

Answer (score 15):

As Mehrdad says, you can't do that on the enum itself. You could however make a couple of extension methods that work on your enum. That will make it look like methods on the enum.

```
static bool IsLessThan(this SizeType first, SizeType second) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't override the compareto method, but you can add an extension method:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> 
Public Function Compare(ByVal obj1 As EnumType, ByVal obj2 As EnumType) as integer
    Dim CompareResults as integer = 0
    'some code  here to do your comparison
    Return CompareResults
End Sub
```

And then execute it as follows:

```
IntegerResult = myEnum.Compare(otherEnum)
```

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx