# Overloading enum operator C# and Silverlight

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Just an academical question:
Is it possible to avoid int casting when comparing Enum to int?

```
int i = 0;
if(i == (int)MyEnum.Whatever)
{
}
```

I would like to overload == operator in such a manner:

```
public static MyEnum operator ==(int lhs, MyEnum rhs)
{}
```

Thanks for reading ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355817/how-do-i-overload-and-operator-for-an-enumeration-in-c). As suggested in that question, you could define an extension method to do the comparison, in order to get rid of the repeated casts.

Comment: I saw that question, but ChrisHDog in that question was asking about overloading operator for two enums, so I had my hopes ;-) But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible. the question is - why do you compare to in at all?

Comment: Because I have int Id from database.

Comment: Comparing enums to int is also very common when talking to an embedded application, or a field bus system, or something.

Comment: Yeah, bit Id#s from a database dont really map to enum ;) Normally. Ints in embedded makes sense. I would cast to enum asap, then go on working comparing enums. Get rid of the "lower level" representation asap.

Comment: IMHO If you consider dogs table and BreedId in every row than in app it is very useful to have enum 'GoldenRetriever' = 1, etc.