# Overloading Operator for Enums

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am a little befuzzled around operator overloading in C#.NET

Please inspect the following example

```
public enum TestActionResult
{
    NoResult,
    Fail,
    Pass,
    Exception
}

TestActionResult result = DetailsScreen.Text.Contains("YOUR DETAILS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && DetailsScreen.Enabled && DetailsScreen.Displayed;
```

What I would like to happen:

I want to automatically convert a `boolean` value into a `TestActionResult`.

So if the boolean value on the right of my result object is true then I would like `TestActionResult` to infer a Pass or Fail if `False`.

I know you can do operator overloading in C# and I am quite sure its possible but I am not familiar with how that would work.

I did have a crack at this but it turns out that was the wrong xD

```
    public static TestActionResult operator == (bool b1, bool b2)
    {
        if(b1 && b2)
        {
            return TestActionResult.Pass;
        }
        return TestActionResult.Fail;
    }

    public static TestActionResult operator !=(bool b1, bool b2)
    {
        if(!(b1 && b2))
        {
            return TestActionResult.Pass;
        }
        return TestActionResult.Fail;
    }
```

Any help would be massively appreciated

I know I can use the Ternary operand however to me it often bloats the lines of code and I would like this to be in a sleeker format

e.g.

```
result = !bodyElement.GetAttribute("class").Contains("popup-visible") ? TestActionResult.Pass : TestActionResult.Fail;
```

This is just too long and if I could reduce it with an operator overload I would really appreciate the input

Comment: It seems Enum Operator Overloading is not possible in C#. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355817/how-do-i-overload-an-operator-for-an-enumeration-in-c

Comment: Where do you want to add these operators? You could create a `struct TestActionResult` which has a property `ActionResult Result`(which is your enum). Then you could add the `bool` implicit operator(or/and the `true`/`false` operators) there.

Comment: Hi Tim, I can add these operands anywhere at the moment, could you provide me a small example?

Comment: @JohnAntonyDanielNolan how about an extension for the bool. bool.ToEnum() i.e ??

Comment: Oh that is interesting, I am quite familiar with extensions and could look into creating an extension to give me a TestActionResult based on the boolean value, I will fall back to this should I not find a solution that suits the questions thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [can't do operator overloading with `enums`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355817/how-do-i-overload-an-operator-for-an-enumeration-in-c) in C#. You could hold this `enum` as property in a `class` or `struct` which is implicitly convertible to `bool` and vice-versa:

```
public enum ActionResult
{
    NoResult,
    Fail,
    Pass,
    Exception
}

public struct TestActionResult
{
    public TestActionResult(ActionResult initialResult)
    {
        Result = initialResult;
    }

    private static readonly TestActionResult PassResult = new TestActionResult { Result = ActionResult.Pass };

    private static readonly TestActionResult FailResult = new TestActionResult { Result = ActionResult.Fail };

    public ActionResult Result { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator TestActionResult(bool b)
    {
        return b ? PassResult : FailResult;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(TestActionResult tar)
    {
        return tar.Result == ActionResult.Pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Helpful info

Answer (score 1):

If you override operator for 2 bools. These operators apply to your project...

I think this makes the simplest.

```
TestActionResult result = DetailsScreen.Text.Contains("YOUR DETAILS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && DetailsScreen.Enabled && DetailsScreen.Displayed 
             ? TestActionResult.Pass 
             : TestActionResult.Failed;
```

Or an extension for the bool

```
public static bool ToEnum(this bool value) {
    return value ? TestActionResult.Pass : TestActionResult.Failed;
}
```

then

```
TestActionResult result =(DetailsScreen.Text.Contains("YOUR DETAILS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && DetailsScreen.Enabled && DetailsScreen.Displayed)
                        .ToEnum();
```

Comment: Thanks Thierry I failed to mention that I would like a solution that does not use ternary operands - I appreciate your help though +1 (Y)